Running numerous MySQL table creates and drops causes a sudden slowdown in query times
I have a PHP script that creates several tables, then later drops all of them. CREATE queries average about 0.05s, while DROP queries average about 0.03s.
However, if I loop the script and run it for long enough, so that tables are getting created, then dropped, then created again ad noseum, the query time eventually suddenly increases by an order of magnitude. Suddenly, CREATE queries average about 0.6s, while DROP queries average about 0.5s.
Why might this slowdown be happening? Are there any ways to prevent or mitigate such a slowdown?
The problem appears to affect all connections. For instance, if I run my PHP script with one database connection, then use the mysql client to create or drop another table, the slowdown that the connection for PHP is experiencing will affect my client's query as well.
If I stop the script for a few minutes, then start it again, it will start fast again, before eventually slowing down. If I start it immediately after stopping, it'll be immediately slow. The longer I wait to restart the process, the longer it'll be fast for after starting again before slowing down.
If I create the tables in memory (ENGINE=MEMORY), the problem does not present.
Here's the profile for one of the CREATE queries:
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000184 |
| Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000025 |
| starting                       | 0.000057 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000040 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.001838 |
| creating table                 | 0.578363 |
| After create                   | 0.000236 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000012 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.182467 |
| query end                      | 0.000067 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000116 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000072 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000080 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000136 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000132 |
+--------------------------------+----------+

And here's the profile for one of the DROP queries:
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000173 |
| Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000031 |
| starting                       | 0.000069 |
| checking permissions           | 0.273770 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000073 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.290310 |
| query end                      | 0.000067 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000023 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000075 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000079 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000145 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000065 |
+--------------------------------+----------+

My MySQL version is 8.0.40-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64.
The output of SHOW VARIABLES is as follows:
Variable_name,Value
activate_all_roles_on_login,OFF
admin_address,
admin_port,33062
admin_ssl_ca,
admin_ssl_capath,
admin_ssl_cert,
admin_ssl_cipher,
admin_ssl_crl,
admin_ssl_crlpath,
admin_ssl_key,
admin_tls_ciphersuites,
admin_tls_version,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
authentication_policy,*,,
auto_generate_certs,ON
auto_increment_increment,1
auto_increment_offset,1
autocommit,ON
automatic_sp_privileges,ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade,OFF
back_log,151
basedir,/usr/
big_tables,OFF
bind_address,127.0.0.1
binlog_cache_size,32768
binlog_checksum,CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates,OFF
binlog_encryption,OFF
binlog_error_action,ABORT_SERVER
binlog_expire_logs_auto_purge,ON
binlog_expire_logs_seconds,2592000
binlog_format,ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay,0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count,0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery,ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time,0
binlog_order_commits,ON
binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup,OFF
binlog_row_event_max_size,8192
binlog_row_image,FULL
binlog_row_metadata,MINIMAL
binlog_row_value_options,
binlog_rows_query_log_events,OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size,32768
binlog_transaction_compression,OFF
binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd,3
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size,25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking,COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode,aes-128-ecb
build_id,47ccd7ae44d1ac1ee8e570cb62c9ef678ae7ec63
bulk_insert_buffer_size,8388608
caching_sha2_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys,ON
caching_sha2_password_digest_rounds,5000
caching_sha2_password_private_key_path,private_key.pem
caching_sha2_password_public_key_path,public_key.pem
character_set_client,utf8mb4
character_set_connection,utf8mb4
character_set_database,utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem,binary
character_set_results,utf8mb4
character_set_server,utf8mb4
character_set_system,utf8mb3
character_sets_dir,/usr/share/mysql/charsets/
check_proxy_users,OFF
collation_connection,utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
collation_database,utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server,utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
completion_type,NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert,AUTO
connect_timeout,10
connection_memory_chunk_size,8192
connection_memory_limit,18446744073709551615
core_file,OFF
create_admin_listener_thread,OFF
cte_max_recursion_depth,1000
datadir,/var/lib/mysql/
default_authentication_plugin,caching_sha2_password
default_collation_for_utf8mb4,utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
default_password_lifetime,0
default_storage_engine,InnoDB
default_table_encryption,OFF
default_tmp_storage_engine,InnoDB
default_week_format,0
delay_key_write,ON
delayed_insert_limit,100
delayed_insert_timeout,300
delayed_queue_size,1000
disabled_storage_engines,
disconnect_on_expired_password,ON
div_precision_increment,4
end_markers_in_json,OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency,OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit,200
error_count,0
event_scheduler,ON
expire_logs_days,0
explain_format,TRADITIONAL
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp,ON
external_user,
flush,OFF
flush_time,0
foreign_key_checks,ON
ft_boolean_syntax,+ -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len,84
ft_min_word_len,4
ft_query_expansion_limit,20
ft_stopword_file,(built-in)
general_log,OFF
general_log_file,/var/log/mysql-general.log
generated_random_password_length,20
global_connection_memory_limit,18446744073709551615
global_connection_memory_tracking,OFF
group_concat_max_len,1024
group_replication_consistency,EVENTUAL
gtid_executed,
gtid_executed_compression_period,0
gtid_mode,OFF
gtid_next,AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned,
gtid_purged,
have_compress,YES
have_dynamic_loading,YES
have_geometry,YES
have_openssl,YES
have_profiling,YES
have_query_cache,NO
have_rtree_keys,YES
have_ssl,YES
have_statement_timeout,YES
have_symlink,DISABLED
histogram_generation_max_mem_size,20000000
host_cache_size,279
hostname,Frodo
identity,0
immediate_server_version,999999
information_schema_stats_expiry,86400
init_connect,
init_file,
init_replica,
init_slave,
innodb_adaptive_flushing,ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm,10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index,ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts,8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay,150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval,5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock,OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog,OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl,OFF
innodb_api_trx_level,0
innodb_autoextend_increment,64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode,2
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size,134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown,ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now,OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct,25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename,ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file,ON
innodb_buffer_pool_instances,1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort,OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup,ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now,OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size,134217728
innodb_change_buffer_max_size,25
innodb_change_buffering,all
innodb_checksum_algorithm,crc32
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled,OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency,0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct,5
innodb_compression_level,6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max,50
innodb_concurrency_tickets,5000
innodb_data_file_path,ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir,
innodb_ddl_buffer_size,1048576
innodb_ddl_threads,4
innodb_deadlock_detect,ON
innodb_dedicated_server,OFF
innodb_default_row_format,dynamic
innodb_directories,
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache,OFF
innodb_doublewrite,ON
innodb_doublewrite_batch_size,0
innodb_doublewrite_dir,
innodb_doublewrite_files,2
innodb_doublewrite_pages,4
innodb_extend_and_initialize,ON
innodb_fast_shutdown,1
innodb_file_per_table,ON
innodb_fill_factor,100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout,1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit,1
innodb_flush_method,fsync
innodb_flush_neighbors,0
innodb_flush_sync,ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops,30
innodb_force_load_corrupted,OFF
innodb_force_recovery,0
innodb_fsync_threshold,0
innodb_ft_aux_table,
innodb_ft_cache_size,8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print,OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword,ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size,84
innodb_ft_min_token_size,3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize,2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit,2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table,
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree,2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size,640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table,
innodb_idle_flush_pct,100
innodb_io_capacity,200
innodb_io_capacity_max,2000
innodb_lock_wait_timeout,50
innodb_log_buffer_size,16777216
innodb_log_checksums,ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages,ON
innodb_log_file_size,50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group,2
innodb_log_group_home_dir,./
innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm,80
innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm,50
innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm,400
innodb_log_write_ahead_size,8192
innodb_log_writer_threads,ON
innodb_lru_scan_depth,1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct,90.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm,10.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag,0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay,0
innodb_max_undo_log_size,1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable,
innodb_monitor_enable,
innodb_monitor_reset,
innodb_monitor_reset_all,
innodb_numa_interleave,OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct,37
innodb_old_blocks_time,1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size,134217728
innodb_open_files,4000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only,OFF
innodb_page_cleaners,1
innodb_page_size,16384
innodb_parallel_read_threads,4
innodb_print_all_deadlocks,OFF
innodb_print_ddl_logs,OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size,300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency,128
innodb_purge_threads,4
innodb_random_read_ahead,OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold,56
innodb_read_io_threads,4
innodb_read_only,OFF
innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs,
innodb_redo_log_capacity,104857600
innodb_redo_log_encrypt,OFF
innodb_replication_delay,0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout,OFF
innodb_rollback_segments,128
innodb_segment_reserve_factor,12.500000
innodb_sort_buffer_size,1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay,6
innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier,50
innodb_stats_auto_recalc,ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked,OFF
innodb_stats_method,nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata,OFF
innodb_stats_persistent,ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages,20
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages,8
innodb_status_output,OFF
innodb_status_output_locks,OFF
innodb_strict_mode,ON
innodb_sync_array_size,1
innodb_sync_spin_loops,30
innodb_table_locks,ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path,ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir,./#innodb_temp/
innodb_thread_concurrency,0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay,10000
innodb_tmpdir,
innodb_undo_directory,./
innodb_undo_log_encrypt,OFF
innodb_undo_log_truncate,ON
innodb_undo_tablespaces,2
innodb_use_fdatasync,OFF
innodb_use_native_aio,ON
innodb_validate_tablespace_paths,ON
innodb_version,8.0.40
innodb_write_io_threads,4
insert_id,0
interactive_timeout,28800
internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine,TempTable
join_buffer_size,262144
keep_files_on_create,OFF
key_buffer_size,16777216
key_cache_age_threshold,300
key_cache_block_size,1024
key_cache_division_limit,100
keyring_operations,ON
large_files_support,ON
large_page_size,0
large_pages,OFF
last_insert_id,0
lc_messages,en_US
lc_messages_dir,/usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names,en_US
license,GPL
local_infile,OFF
lock_wait_timeout,31536000
locked_in_memory,OFF
log_bin,ON
log_bin_basename,/var/lib/mysql/binlog
log_bin_index,/var/lib/mysql/binlog.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators,OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events,OFF
log_error,/var/log/mysql/error.log
log_error_services,log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal
log_error_suppression_list,
log_error_verbosity,2
log_output,FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes,OFF
log_raw,OFF
log_replica_updates,ON
log_slave_updates,ON
log_slow_admin_statements,ON
log_slow_extra,OFF
log_slow_replica_statements,OFF
log_slow_slave_statements,OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog,ON
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes,0
log_timestamps,UTC
long_query_time,0.200000
low_priority_updates,OFF
lower_case_file_system,OFF
lower_case_table_names,0
mandatory_roles,
master_info_repository,TABLE
master_verify_checksum,OFF
max_allowed_packet,67108864
max_binlog_cache_size,18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size,104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size,18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors,100
max_connections,151
max_delayed_threads,20
max_digest_length,1024
max_error_count,1024
max_execution_time,0
max_heap_table_size,16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads,20
max_join_size,18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data,4096
max_points_in_geometry,65536
max_prepared_stmt_count,16382
max_relay_log_size,0
max_seeks_for_key,18446744073709551615
max_sort_length,1024
max_sp_recursion_depth,0
max_user_connections,0
max_write_lock_count,18446744073709551615
min_examined_row_limit,0
myisam_data_pointer_size,6
myisam_max_sort_file_size,9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size,18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options,BACKUP
myisam_sort_buffer_size,8388608
myisam_stats_method,nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap,OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users,OFF
mysqlx_bind_address,127.0.0.1
mysqlx_compression_algorithms,DEFLATE_STREAM,LZ4_MESSAGE,ZSTD_STREAM
mysqlx_connect_timeout,30
mysqlx_deflate_default_compression_level,3
mysqlx_deflate_max_client_compression_level,5
mysqlx_document_id_unique_prefix,0
mysqlx_enable_hello_notice,ON
mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout,60
mysqlx_interactive_timeout,28800
mysqlx_lz4_default_compression_level,2
mysqlx_lz4_max_client_compression_level,8
mysqlx_max_allowed_packet,67108864
mysqlx_max_connections,100
mysqlx_min_worker_threads,2
mysqlx_port,33060
mysqlx_port_open_timeout,0
mysqlx_read_timeout,30
mysqlx_socket,/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysqlx_ssl_ca,
mysqlx_ssl_capath,
mysqlx_ssl_cert,
mysqlx_ssl_cipher,
mysqlx_ssl_crl,
mysqlx_ssl_crlpath,
mysqlx_ssl_key,
mysqlx_wait_timeout,28800
mysqlx_write_timeout,60
mysqlx_zstd_default_compression_level,3
mysqlx_zstd_max_client_compression_level,11
net_buffer_length,16384
net_read_timeout,30
net_retry_count,10
net_write_timeout,60
new,OFF
ngram_token_size,2
offline_mode,OFF
old,OFF
old_alter_table,OFF
open_files_limit,10000
optimizer_max_subgraph_pairs,100000
optimizer_prune_level,1
optimizer_search_depth,62
optimizer_switch,index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,use_invisible_indexes=off,skip_scan=on,hash_join=on,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=on,hypergraph_optimizer=off,derived_condition_pushdown=on
optimizer_trace,enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features,greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit,1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size,1048576
optimizer_trace_offset,-1
original_commit_timestamp,36028797018963968
original_server_version,999999
parser_max_mem_size,18446744073709551615
partial_revokes,OFF
password_history,0
password_require_current,OFF
password_reuse_interval,0
performance_schema,ON
performance_schema_accounts_size,-1
performance_schema_digests_size,10000
performance_schema_error_size,5313
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size,10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size,10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size,10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size,10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size,10
performance_schema_hosts_size,-1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes,150
performance_schema_max_cond_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_digest_length,1024
performance_schema_max_digest_sample_age,60
performance_schema_max_file_classes,80
performance_schema_max_file_handles,32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_index_stat,-1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes,450
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks,-1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes,350
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_program_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes,60
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes,10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length,1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes,175
performance_schema_max_statement_classes,219
performance_schema_max_statement_stack,10
performance_schema_max_table_handles,-1
performance_schema_max_table_instances,-1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat,-1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes,100
performance_schema_max_thread_instances,-1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size,512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size,-1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size,-1
performance_schema_show_processlist,OFF
performance_schema_users_size,-1
persist_only_admin_x509_subject,
persist_sensitive_variables_in_plaintext,ON
persisted_globals_load,ON
pid_file,/var/lib/mysql/Frodo.pid
plugin_dir,/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
port,3306
preload_buffer_size,32768
print_identified_with_as_hex,OFF
profiling,OFF
profiling_history_size,15
protocol_compression_algorithms,zlib,zstd,uncompressed
protocol_version,10
proxy_user,
pseudo_replica_mode,OFF
pseudo_slave_mode,OFF
pseudo_thread_id,997
query_alloc_block_size,8192
query_prealloc_size,8192
rand_seed1,0
rand_seed2,0
range_alloc_block_size,4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size,8388608
rbr_exec_mode,STRICT
read_buffer_size,131072
read_only,OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size,262144
regexp_stack_limit,8000000
regexp_time_limit,32
relay_log,Frodo-relay-bin
relay_log_basename,/var/lib/mysql/Frodo-relay-bin
relay_log_index,/var/lib/mysql/Frodo-relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file,relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository,TABLE
relay_log_purge,ON
relay_log_recovery,OFF
relay_log_space_limit,0
replica_allow_batching,ON
replica_checkpoint_group,512
replica_checkpoint_period,300
replica_compressed_protocol,OFF
replica_exec_mode,STRICT
replica_load_tmpdir,/tmp
replica_max_allowed_packet,1073741824
replica_net_timeout,60
replica_parallel_type,LOGICAL_CLOCK
replica_parallel_workers,4
replica_pending_jobs_size_max,134217728
replica_preserve_commit_order,ON
replica_skip_errors,OFF
replica_sql_verify_checksum,ON
replica_transaction_retries,10
replica_type_conversions,
replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config,OFF
replication_sender_observe_commit_only,OFF
report_host,
report_password,
report_port,3306
report_user,
require_row_format,OFF
require_secure_transport,OFF
resultset_metadata,FULL
rpl_read_size,8192
rpl_stop_replica_timeout,31536000
rpl_stop_slave_timeout,31536000
schema_definition_cache,256
secondary_engine_cost_threshold,100000.000000
secure_file_priv,/var/lib/mysql-files/
select_into_buffer_size,131072
select_into_disk_sync,OFF
select_into_disk_sync_delay,0
server_id,1
server_id_bits,32
server_uuid,64fdb9d6-bbc5-11ea-a55d-0028f8c88d22
session_track_gtids,OFF
session_track_schema,ON
session_track_state_change,OFF
session_track_system_variables,time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info,OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys,ON
sha256_password_private_key_path,private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users,OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path,public_key.pem
show_create_table_skip_secondary_engine,OFF
show_create_table_verbosity,OFF
show_gipk_in_create_table_and_information_schema,ON
show_old_temporals,OFF
skip_external_locking,ON
skip_name_resolve,OFF
skip_networking,OFF
skip_replica_start,OFF
skip_show_database,OFF
skip_slave_start,OFF
slave_allow_batching,ON
slave_checkpoint_group,512
slave_checkpoint_period,300
slave_compressed_protocol,OFF
slave_exec_mode,STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir,/tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet,1073741824
slave_net_timeout,60
slave_parallel_type,LOGICAL_CLOCK
slave_parallel_workers,4
slave_pending_jobs_size_max,134217728
slave_preserve_commit_order,ON
slave_rows_search_algorithms,INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN
slave_skip_errors,OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum,ON
slave_transaction_retries,10
slave_type_conversions,
slow_launch_time,2
slow_query_log,ON
slow_query_log_file,/var/log/mysql/slow-query.log
socket,/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size,262144
source_verify_checksum,OFF
sql_auto_is_null,OFF
sql_big_selects,ON
sql_buffer_result,OFF
sql_generate_invisible_primary_key,OFF
sql_log_bin,ON
sql_log_off,OFF
sql_mode,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes,ON
sql_quote_show_create,ON
sql_replica_skip_counter,0
sql_require_primary_key,OFF
sql_safe_updates,OFF
sql_select_limit,18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter,0
sql_warnings,OFF
ssl_ca,ca.pem
ssl_capath,
ssl_cert,server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher,
ssl_crl,
ssl_crlpath,
ssl_fips_mode,OFF
ssl_key,server-key.pem
ssl_session_cache_mode,ON
ssl_session_cache_timeout,300
statement_id,12448
stored_program_cache,256
stored_program_definition_cache,256
super_read_only,OFF
sync_binlog,1
sync_master_info,10000
sync_relay_log,10000
sync_relay_log_info,10000
sync_source_info,10000
system_time_zone,PST
table_definition_cache,2000
table_encryption_privilege_check,OFF
table_open_cache,4000
table_open_cache_instances,16
tablespace_definition_cache,256
temptable_max_mmap,1073741824
temptable_max_ram,1073741824
temptable_use_mmap,ON
terminology_use_previous,NONE
thread_cache_size,9
thread_handling,one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack,1048576
time_zone,SYSTEM
timestamp,1732574113.782329
tls_ciphersuites,
tls_version,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
tmp_table_size,16777216
tmpdir,/tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size,8192
transaction_allow_batching,OFF
transaction_isolation,REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size,4096
transaction_read_only,OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction,XXHASH64
unique_checks,ON
updatable_views_with_limit,YES
use_secondary_engine,ON
version,8.0.40-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
version_comment,(Ubuntu)
version_compile_machine,x86_64
version_compile_os,Linux
version_compile_zlib,1.3.1
wait_timeout,28800
warning_count,0
windowing_use_high_precision,ON
xa_detach_on_prepare,ON

I've posted the output of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS to PasteBin.


How much RAM do you have?
innodb_buffer_pool_size is a terribly small 128MB; if you have more than 4GB of available ram, raise that setting to 70% of available RAM.
Are you doing a lot of UNLOCK TABLES?  (I would expect you to do none.)
The STATUS values smell like they were taken via SHOW STATUS; (one user) and not SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; (system-wide).  (I have no way of being sure, just that some of the numbers look "too small".)

